# Kendo UI Tabstrip 1 on click

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to make an `alert` when click on `Tab 1` only, but seem it not working. Appreciate your help here.

```js
<div id="tabstrip">
  <ul>
    <li>Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
 <div>Content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>Content 2</div>
</div>

<script>
  var tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");

  tabStrip.select("li:first");  
  $("#tabstrip").on("click", function() {
      tabStrip.select(1);   
      alert("hi");
  });
</script>
```

[full demo in here](https://dojo.telerik.com/AfOvElUx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are setting the onclick function to the whole tabstrip. Try it like this:

```
$("#tabstrip li:first").on("click", function() {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: yes, I notice that. But I couldn't able to find `#tabstrip li:first`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Additionally you can use the onSelect event function to identify the selected element anytime.

```
var onSelect = function(e) {
        var a = e.item.innerText;
        console.log(e.item.innerText);
        if(a ==="Tab 1"){
          console.log("Tab 1 selected");
        }


     };
```

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip/events/select